# Add Xml namespace using Jaxb

Tags: java, namespaces, jaxb, amazon-web-services

I am creating amazon feed, the feed xml should be like:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
```

I am using jaxb to generate xml files from java classes, I used NamespacePrefixMapperImpl from jaxb samples to add namespaces to the xml. But currently it generates the root like:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

how I can remove the xmlns from amzn-envelope.xsd??

Here's the mapping I used in NamespacePrefixMapperImpl

```
if( "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".equals(namespaceUri) )
    return "xsi";

if("amzn-envelope.xsd".equals(namespaceUri))
    return "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a property at Marshaller that can add the amzn-envelope.xsd:

```
marshaller.setProperty("jaxb.noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "amzn-envelope.xsd");
```

and left the NamespacePrefixMapper to add the "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance".
Hope this helps others.

Comment: I don't think the NamespacePrefixMapper is necessary. Setting the noNamespaceSchemaLocation should be enough. The "xsi" namespace will be added automatically (at least when using Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent, your document has a default namespace, and you're trying to add the `schemalLocation` for that namespace.

`NamespacePrefixMapper` won't let you do this, it's useful only for picking a prefix for a namespace. There are no namespaces in this document, and so no useful way of using `NamespacePrefixMapper`. It can't be used for adding `schemaLocation` hints - those are treated specially by JAXB, and you're just confusing it.

Are you sure you need the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"` at all? Have you tried sending it to the web service without it?

Comment: Yes, I send without it and returns error

<Result>
    <MessageID>0</MessageID>
    <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
    <ResultMessageCode>6001</ResultMessageCode>
    <ResultDescription>XML parse error at line 2, column 17: Unknown element &apos;AmazonEnvelope&apos;</ResultDescription>
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <SKU>0</SKU>
    </AdditionalInfo>
   </Result>